# Not able to Save workitem template: There is a issue on the server. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am facing this error when i am trying to add new field in Bug workitem.

Failed to save the 'Bug' Work Item Type to the server.

There is a problem on the server. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

I have tried creating workitem field by connecting to the tfs server itself with admin account. Interestingly i am able to import the backedup Bug.xml

Looks like any new changes to structure of Workitem template database is throwing this error.

**But i am able to add new fields and save the workitem template in the New Team project collection.**

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

**eventvwr log:**

**TF53010**: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 12/10/2012 9:23:18 AM
Machine: BA2K8BATFS
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/8080/ROOT/tfs-1-129995617805927561
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Service Host: f03592d1-d250-405e-b696-5ad489d5f953 (batfs)
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 7400
  Thread Id: 3848
  Account name: NETIKLLC\Batfsadmin

**Detailed Message: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.**

Web Request Details
    Url: http://:8080/tfs/_tfs_resources/WorkItemTracking/v4.0/ClientService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (witadmin.exe, 10.0.40219.1)
    Headers: Content-Length=16491&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8%3b+action%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fWorkItemTracking%2fClientServices%2f03%2fUpdate%22&Accept-Encoding=gzip&Accept-Language=en-US&Expect=100-continue&Host=%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(witadmin.exe%2c+10.0.40219.1)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=75f2f259-f06b-4d99-8a29-4831f8d4191b
    Path: /tfs/_tfs_resources/WorkItemTracking/v4.0/ClientService.asmx
    Local Request: True
    Host Address: 
    User: NETIKLLC\Batfsadmin [authentication type: NTLM]

Comment: But i am able to add new fields and save the workitem template in the New Team project collection.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you have no rights for for adding it . you should have in the administrative group . or the group which have the rights of creating fields , project ,edit or delete.
check the project collection group membership from "team" on the tool bar! or right click on project and select " TEam Project Setting".
vote up answer if it helps thanks!